# How to produce an application that will run on OS X 10.7+ instead of requiring 10.11?

Tags: macos, qt, cmake, version

I am attempting to build a Qt application on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) which will run on 10.7 (Lion) or later releases. I've got the following key in the `.app`'s `Info.plist`:

```
<key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
<string>10.7.0</string>
```

However, when I attempt to launch the application on a clean 10.10 (Yosemite) installation, I end up with the following confusing error:

[image: Weird Error]

The binary inside the bundle works fine if run manually through the terminal. Why can't I launch the application directly in 10.10?

#### Build Environment:

- OS X 10.11.3
- Xcode 7.2
- Qt 5.5.0
- CMake 3.4.2

For reference, the source code for the application is located [here](https://github.com/nitroshare/nitroshare-desktop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XCode's settings for a project, you need to set the Deployment Target to the lowest operating system you want your application to run on. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW47) states:

> The deployment target setting specifies the lowest operating system version that your app can run on.

This is relevant for both iOS and OS X.

In XCode, you can set the filter to 'version' (top right) and you'll see the Deployment Target option, which in this case is set to 10.8

[image]

I suspect the `LSMinimumSystemVersion` key is just one of the values that the operating system checks. Should an application be linked to libraries required by newer OS SDK features, changing the key alone is not going to be able to work.

Whilst you're asking about Qt and CMake, you need to use the equivalent CMake option, which I expect is **CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET**, as listed in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.html)

Comment: Indeed. The combination of CMake flags that finally produced a working executable were `-DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.8" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add compilation flag `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7` - however I've found out recently that compiling on 10.11 with `-mmacosx-verison-min=10.7` produces binary with runtime errors - when changed to 10.8 as minimum version it worked fine